# How to use "If empty" or "if (isset)" in this scenario

Tags: php, url, if-statement

In my site, I allow my users to upload an avatar. The following code is used to print the URL:

```
$r = $r . $photoUrl = '/wp-content/uploads/userphoto/' . get_user_meta($user_info->ID, 'userphoto_thumb_file', true);
```

This will give us for example `/wp-content/uploads/userphoto/2.thumbnail.png`.

The problem is that if the user has not uploaded an avatar, the URL will of course be `/wp-content/uploads/userphoto/`. So it will be a broken image.

I want to display a custom image for users with no avatar, for example `no-image.png`. I'm *guessing* that this is done by adding an `if (isset)` statement there? I can't seem to figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `empty`:

```
$image_id = get_user_meta($user_info->ID, 'userphoto_thumb_file', true);
$r = $r . $photoUrl = '/wp-content/uploads/userphoto/' . (empty($image_id) ? 'no-image.png' : $image_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, depending on if get_user_meta actually returns Null.

```
if (is_null(get_user_meta($user_info->ID, 'userphoto_thumb_file', true))) {
    $r = $r . $photoUrl = '/wp-content/uploads/userphoto/customimage.png';
} else {
    $r = $r . $photoUrl = '/wp-content/uploads/userphoto/' . get_user_meta($user_info->ID, 'userphoto_thumb_file', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
if(!empty(get_user_meta($user_info->ID, 'userphoto_thumb_file', true)))
{
    $r = $r . $photoUrl = '/wp-content/uploads/userphoto/' . get_user_meta($user_info->ID, 'userphoto_thumb_file', true);
}
else
{
        $r = $r . $photoUrl = '/wp-content/uploads/userphoto/no-image.png';   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should test if the file exists :

```
if(!file_exists( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $r))  { 
   $r = '/path/to/default/image.jpg';
}
```

With this approach, even if the user has uploaded an avatar, but for some reason the image is not present on the server, it will display the default avatar.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just check if the function returns something that evaluates to `false`. An empty string evaluates to `false` in php.

```
$img = get_user_meta($user_info->ID, 'userphoto_thumb_file', true);

if(!$img) {
    $img = 'no-image.png';
}

$r = $r . $photoUrl = '/wp-content/uploads/userphoto/' . $img;
```